# R unwantedly converting character to date instead of numeric

Tags: r, linux

I'm passing arguements from a shell script to an R script and R.

```
library(rLandsat) #used later in the script
args<-commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)

max_date = Sys.Date()-as.numeric(args[1])
min_date = Sys.Date()-(as.numeric(args[1])+as.numeric(args[2]))
path<-as.numeric(as.character(args[4]))
row<-as.numeric(as.character(args[5]))
cloud<-as.numeric(as.character(args[6]))
foldername<-as.character(args[7])
for(i in args){
    print(typeof(i))
}
print(args)
print(c(max_date,min_date,path,row,cloud,foldername))
for(i in c(max_date,min_date,path,row,cloud,foldername)){
    print(typeof(i))
}
```

and R is for some reason converting the arguments to some type of date that is still a character. Here is the output from the script. `args[3]` is used later but I should probably check that too. I know the `arg` is already a character but it returned the same values with only `as.numeric()` for `path row` and `cloud`. The first two arguments are returned correctly `"2016-12-31" "2016-01-01"` but the others I would like the same value as the original argument returned. Will check out `list()` instead of `c()`

```
[1] "character"
[1] "character"
[1] "character"
[1] "character"
[1] "character"
[1] "character"
[1] "1048"        "365"         "Yellowstone" "38"          "29"
[6] "20"          "2016"
[1] "2016-12-31" "2016-01-01" "1970-02-08" "1970-01-30" "1970-01-21"
[6] "1975-07-10"
[1] "character"
[1] "character"
[1] "character"
[1] "character"
[1] "character"
[1] "character"
```

Comment: the culprit is `c`. use `list` instead if you want to retain the original type. See `?c`

Comment: Or make everything numeric before putting it in `c()`. You say what you don't like, but don't say what you want, so I'm not sure of your goal, but if you want everything to be numeric, including the numeric representation of dates (in days since Jan 1, 1970), use, e.g., `max_date = as.numeric(Sys.Date()-as.numeric(args[1]))`

Comment: Yes! the error was with ```c()```. I'm getting type ```double``` instead of numeric for the ```as.numeric(as.character())``` arguments but glad its no longer a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`c()` was causing the error. See MichaelChirico's comment

Answer (score 0):

You really should look into lubridate package to make operations involving dates https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/raw/master/lubridate.pdf

As a rule of thumb when you combine data with different classes they are coerced to a format. This happens frequently in the c() command. In your case mixing dates and numerics might get you mixed results.